# Good undergraduate complex analysis textbook

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a textbook aimed at undergraduate students (i.e. a first exposition of complex analysis) but not geared towards applications as Churchill and, if possible, assuming the mathematical maturity a real analysis and an abstract algebra undergrad courses give but not much more (i.e. not extremely terse). Which book is suited for me? I've heard Ahlfors and Conway are good, but aren't those grad-level courses?

Oh, I almost forgot, this is for self-studying so intuition and some examples are appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: The theory of functions of a complex variable by Sveshnikov and Tikhonov (Mir publishers) Google it!

Comment: I really like Stein and Shakarchi. Another good one (extremely in-depth) is Markushevich.

Comment: One of my favorite complex analysis https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387950699/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1477463740&sr=8-2&keywords=complex+analysis  The exercises are nontrivial and the exposition is very enjoyable.

Comment: I also recomment Stein & Shakarchi.

Answer (score 2):

Complex Analysis / Edition 1
by THEODORE GAMELIN is very intuitive, and teaches you not only the theory, but also the execution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Bak&Newman's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441972870).

Very lucid, good examples, covers a wide range of topics (progressively it becomes somewhat challenging but the first ~3/5s of the book are a great undergrad introduction)

Answer (score 0):

**An Introduction to Complex Function Theory** - Bruce P. Palka.

This is a very elementary textbook, but it still covers some very cool stuff in a rigorous way.